# Cannot run mongoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to work with node.js and mongoDB so I installed mongoDB om my computer, I ran mongod.exe and mongo.exe. But when I try to install the Node.js MongoDB Driver this is printed:

[image]

So I tried to install kerberos using the following commands:

```
npm install -g node-gyp

git clone https://github.com/christkv/kerberos.git

cd kerberos

npm install

node-gyp rebuild
```

But when npm installs kerberos' dependencies I get the following screen:

[image]

It says I can pass the --python switch to point to Python but how to I do that and will that enable me to install mongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to install kerberos, why do you clone it from github and install manually? You can just 'npm install --save' it.

Next, the python path can be specified as follows: --python=/usr/bin/python2 . Of course you have to change the path to python2 binary appropriate to your system. I'd expect something like

```
--python=C:\program_files\oh_my_python\python2.exe
```